# Delete Blank Rows after exporting from Datagridview to excel

Tags: vb.net

Good day Guys. This Code enables me to export datagridview to excel excluding invisible rows using button.

The problems is. this code leaves a blank rows in my excel everytime datagridview.row is invisible.

Can someone help me how to delete a blank row using excel-vba macro? after the "NEXT I"  line?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
    Dim I, J As Short
    xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application


    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

    Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlapp.Visible = True
    rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

    With excelWorksheet
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.Delete()
        Dim curCol As Short = 0
        For iC = 0 To colsTotal
            If DataGridView1.Columns(iC).Visible Then
                .Cells(1, curCol + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
                curCol += 1
            End If

        Next

        For I = 0 To rowsTotal
            curCol = 0
            For J = 0 To colsTotal
                DataGridView1.Rows(I).Visible = True
                .Cells(I + 2, curCol + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(J).Value
                curCol += 1
            Next J

        Next I

        .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 10
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        .Cells(1, 1).Select()


        excelWorksheet.SaveAs("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlapp.Quit()
        xlapp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlapp)
        releaseObject(excelBook)
        releaseObject(excelWorksheet)

    End With

    MsgBox("You can find the file E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    Dim res As MsgBoxResult
    res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open the file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        Process.Start("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of deleting blank rows later, why not skip them while adding to the sheet?

Comment: my code is actually skipping them. the problem it leaves a blank rows because of my for loop function. i think theres' something wrong with it.

Comment: nevermind. i've resolved it already. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variables to get next cell of DataGridView and Excel Sheet, that is why it is inserting blank rows for invisible rows/columns

```
' variables to access grid cell
Dim gvRow as Integer = 0, gvCol as Integer = 0

' variables to access excel cell
Dim exRow as Integer = 0, exCol as Integer = 0

For gvRow = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    exCol = 0
    If DataGridView1.Rows(gvRow).Visible Then
        For gvCol = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            If DataGridView1.Columns(gvCol).Visible Then
                .Cells(exRow, exCol).value = DataGridView1.Rows(gvRow).Cells(gvCol).Value
                exCol += 1
            End If
        Next gvCol
        exRow += 1
    End If
Next gvRow
```

Comment: Resolved, that's great. I'll leave this answer here, so it may help someone other searching for similar solution.